# Locate the source file of a web page streaming video

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension, jdownloader

Consider the video of the following web-page (you need to log-in with your facebook account or similar for watching it):

[streaming video](http://www.video.mediaset.it/video/quinta_colonna/full/puntata-dell-8-febbraio_593437.html#)

common chrome extensions locate the source file of the video at:

[link of source video](http://free-prd1.cdn.mediaset.net/mp4/2016/02/152c33b15c3965-14_0.mp4)

from where I can download it.

I would like to know:

Searching on the surface of the web-page source code, that link can't be found. At high level of abstraction, how such extensions parse the web page and locate that link?

Comment: I don't see a video on that webpage (do we need to log in?).  If the link is inserted dynamically, then you'd need to wait until it's there before looking for the source.

Comment: Are you trying to make people login to this? I am not randomly logging it to an Italian website. It's also _not guaranteed_ that you can just steal any video like that, there are measures in place to prevent this. And I can't see the video (without logging in I guess) either, so it might be flash or silverlight?